# Keep enter space in text column when converting to csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, xlsx

I have data in excel where is text with enter space in last column. Here is examples of my data:

[image]

**If I convert using python to csv, my data looks like this:**

[image]

**I need the TEXT column will be like this:**

[image]

This is my script:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np


WD = r'XXX'
os.chdir(WD) 

for file in os.listdir(WD):
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        FILE = file

        sheet_names = pd.ExcelFile(FILE).sheet_names  

        for sn in sheet_names:
            OUTPUT_FILE = '{}_{}'.format(sn,FILE.replace('.xlsx','.csv'))
            df = pd.read_excel(FILE,)
            print(FILE, sn)

            for col in df.columns.to_list():
                df[col] = df[col].map({True: '', False: ''}).fillna(df[col])


                cn = ['IN', 'NAME', 'TEXT']
                df = df.reindex(columns = cn)

                df.to_csv(OUTPUT_FILE,sep='|',encoding='utf-8-sig',index=False)
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this works for your solution, (pip install xlsxwriter) before executing

**Excel to csv:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('./keep_enter.xlsx')
def replace_custom_func(x):
    new_str = ''
    if len(x) > 0:
        for i in x.split('\n'):
            new_str += f'"{i}"&CHAR(10)&'
        return "=" + new_str[:-10]
    else:
        return x
df['Text'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda x: replace_custom_func(x))
df.to_csv('keep_enter1.csv', sep='|', index=False)
```

**CSV to Excel:**

```
df = pd.read_csv('./keep_enter1.csv', sep='|')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('new_excel_replace12345.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# # Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

# # Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
format = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True})
worksheet.set_column('C:D', None, format)
worksheet.write_formula(1, 2, df['Text'][0])
# # Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Bud I have now in text this :  Lives in England \nbirth: 12.08.2005 \nHis hobby is cycling. I  want to keep the same format as in xlsx when I converting the text column to csv

Comment: In excel If you press alt+enter, it gives a new line in a cell and in text it convert it to \n. Do your excel contains (enter space) as a text? If so just use df.to_csv('keep_enter1.csv', sep='|', index=False)

Comment: My excel doesn´t contains (enter space) as a text. I wrote this just to make it clear what it is about. Sorry, maybe this seems confusing. But the text is as new line in the cell.

Comment: I put the screen of my file above

Comment: If you press alt+enter it will take a line break in excel so when you read_excel the excel file it will replace the new line with \n.

Comment: I edit my solution, kindly check again

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-), but this code doesn´t work right for me. I don´t know why.... but the result you can see in answer (here I can not upload the picture